# Referencing a YAML config file, from Python, when a softlink is defined

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, config

I have the following code;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import yaml

with open('config.yml', 'r') as config_file:
    config = yaml.load(config_file)
```

The file is called `__init__.py` which is in the directory `~/bin/myprogram/myprogram/` and in the same directory, I have a file called `config.yml`

My symlink is as follows;

```
user$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/

lrwxr-xr-x    1 user  admin        55 27 Nov 13:25 myprogram -> /Users/user/bin/myprogram/myprogram/__init__.py
```

Every time I run myprogram, I get the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.yml'`. I believe this is because the `config.yml` is not in `/usr/local/bin/`. What is the best way to work around this issue?

Comment: @sufiyan-ghori yes, if I run it relative (python3 `__init__.py`) it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__file__` to access the location of the `__init__.py` file when executing code in that file. It returns the full path, but care has to be taken as it may be the `.pyc` (or `.pyo`) version. Since you are using Python3 I would use the pathlib module:

```
import yaml
from pathlib import Path

my_path = Path(__file__).resolve()  # resolve to get rid of any symlinks
config_path = my_path.parent / 'config.yaml'

with config_path.open() as config_file:
    config = yaml.safe_load(config_file)
```

Please note:

- If you have to use PyYAML, use `safe_load()`, even PyYAML's own documentation indicates `.load()` can be unsafe. It almost never necessary to use that. And in the unlikely event that `safe_load()` cannot load your config, e.g. if it has `!!python/...` tags, you should explicitly add register the classes that you actually need to the `SafeLoader`).
- Since [September 2006](http://web.archive.org/web/20060924190202/http://yaml.org/faq.html) the [recommended extension for YAML files](http://yaml.org/faq.html) has been `.yaml`

Comment: When I run `config_path = my_path.parent('config.yml')`, I get `TypeError: 'PosixPath' object is not callable`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dan Sorry, I did not run the code, and made an error. The resulting "parent" Path should not be called, but the filename "concatenated" with the `/` operator.